# Vertical timeline react

Tags: reactjs

I am making a single page portfolio website with the navigation bar at the top whose position is sticky. When I create the vertical-timeline, it overflows over the nav bar.

```
import React from "react";
import { VerticalTimeline, VerticalTimelineElement } from "react-vertical-timeline-component";
import "react-vertical-timeline-component/style.min.css";
import SchoolIcon from "@material-ui/icons/School";
import "../styles/Experience.css"

function Experience() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="experience" id="experience">
                <VerticalTimeline lineColor="#3e497a" animate={true} visible={false}>
                    <VerticalTimelineElement
                        date="2018-2022"
                        iconStyle={{background: "#3e497a", color: "#fff"}}
                        icon={<SchoolIcon />}
                        animate={true} visible={false}
                    >
                        <h2 className="vertical-timeline-element-title">
                            Udgam School, India
                        </h2>
                        <p> High School Diploma </p>
                    </VerticalTimelineElement>

                    <VerticalTimelineElement 
                        className="vertical-timeline-element--education"
                        date="2022-2026(expected graduation)"
                        iconStyle={{background: "#3e497a", color: "#fff"}}
                        icon={<SchoolIcon />}
                    >
                        <h2 className="vertical-timeline-element-title">
                            Purdue University, West Lafayette
                        </h2>
                        <h3 className="vertical-timeline-element-subtitle">
                            Honors College
                        </h3>
                        <h4>
                            Bachelors of Science
                        </h4>
                    </VerticalTimelineElement>

                </VerticalTimeline>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Experience
```

[this is what the overflow looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPFaG.png)

I want to do something to prevent the timeline from overflowing into the nav bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider applying a positive `z-index` to the navigation bar that is greater than the stacking context element's `z-index` that holds the vertical timeline elements within the same stacking context.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav style="position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 100; background-color: slateblue; padding: 1em;">
  Sticky Navigation Bar
</nav>

<div style="position: relative; z-index: 50; background-color: pink; height: 200vh">
  Vertical timeline element
</div>
```